# Reverting C#.Net app to build as debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Okay I'm new on c#.net development, I made a small program and it was all fine running/building it while I was in a process of coding it BUT after I finished it and tried to publish it, error occurred saying "Signing Tool" is not found. Now I don't want to install the signing tool, but I can't get my project back the way it was, every time I build it blocks me off by that error.

Let just say how can I tell to VB to treat my run as a debug building not publish building?

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: VS2015 community

Comment: no, im not trying to complete my publishing, I just wanted to build my app again without asking for the signing tool just like before I tried to publish it

Comment: nvm, i found the answer on one of the answers from there, thanks!